# passenger-config stderr: *** An error occured while querying the Phusion Passenger(R) server: Not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, passenger

I tried to deploy my app with Capistrano but it gave me an error while processing.
It is work, but not restarted.

Please help, what could be the reason for the error when restarting the passenger

**cap production deploy "RAILS_ENV=production"**

```
    passenger:restart
      01 passenger-config restart-app /home/myapp --ignore-app-not-running
      01 *** An error occured while querying the Phusion Passenger(R) server:
      01 Not found
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
```

**deploy.rb**

```
namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end
```

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
passenger_root /home/btsreport/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/passenger-6.0.1;
passenger_ruby /home/btsreport/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/wrappers/ruby;
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.com;

    # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    root /home/myapp/current/public;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Turn on Passenger
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env    production;

}
```

**passenger-config restart-app:**

```
*** An error occured while querying the Phusion Passenger(R) server:
Not found
```

**passenger-config --root**

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
```

**passenger-status**

```
Version : 6.0.15
Date    : 2023-09-06 10:27:05 +0300
Instance: LaQ7yZDe (nginx/1.20.2 Phusion_Passenger/6.0.1)

----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 6
App groups    : 1
Processes     : 1
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/home/myapp/current (production):
  App root: /home/myapp/current
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 30221   Sessions: 0       Processed: 1544    Uptime: 6d 13h 44m 26s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 153M    Last used: 1h 4
```

**sudo nginx -t**

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```